# Velocity chart and Burn-up chart from Azure Devops to PowerBI

Tags: azure, azure-devops, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

There are lot of unanswered questions on this area and it would be appreciated if someone takes a dig at it.

I am trying to replicate the Velocity chart and Burnup chart from Azure Devops to PowerBI, Is it possible to get the data from Azure DevOps by analytic view or Rest API into Power BI desktop?

I have referred few links but unable to get the solution.

Is there any straight forward way to get the exact data or query used by Azuredevops and connect that data to powerbi?

Unable to calculate planned and completed late data correctly.
Currently using work items-current data table

Here are links I referred:

1. https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/burnup-charts-powerbi-ferry-van-der-vorst
2. https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/create-velocity-chart-powerbi-ferry-van-der-vorst

Thank you and appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Since we have a direct column called state (consist of work item which are complete, inprogress, resolved, done etc.) in the data we export to PowerBI from Azuredevops by analytics views but do not have any direct calculation for items which were planned during the start of each sprint as the work item changes it state everytime it is updated and/or it is difficult to track if the item was completed late after the sprint.
I am looking specifically on how do you calculated Planned and Completed late work items from the data.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get a Sprint Velocity chart from Azure Devops Boards Analytics view to Power BI. You will need to add different calculated columns and build a visual.
Refer this ->
Column 1: Is Last Day in Iteration =
ISBLANK (CALCULATE (
COUNTROWS ( 'View Name' ),
ALLEXCEPT ( 'View Name', 'View Name'[Work Item Id] ),
'View Name'[Date] > EARLIER ( 'View Name'[Date] ),
'View Name'[Iteration Path] = EARLIER ( 'View Name'[Iteration Path] )
))

This will provide True/false values for each work item's last day in iteration.
You can use this column as true/false values and state of the work item
to create a spillover column.

Like this one has to continue creating 2 more columns for item added in sprint on sprint start date and in between.

Hope this helps. I know this is not a complete solution but a good point to start.